# How to get value from all selected dropdownlist items

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table id="tb_Answers">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="ddl_NextQuestion" name="_ctl0">
                    <option value="0">End</option>
                    <option value="95">ans 1</option>
                    <option value="96">ans 2</option>
                    <option value="97">ans 3</option>
                    <option value="98">ans 4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <select class="ddl_NextQuestion" runat="server">
                </td>
                <td>
        </tr>
        <select class="ddl_NextQuestion" runat="server">
            </td>
            <td>
                </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I got here 3 ddl i selected item in each one of them i need to get all  values from all selected ddl items with class "ddl_nextQuestion" some think like this

```
var arrAns= $.map($('select.ddl_NextQuestion.options[ddl_NextQuestions.selectedIndex].value'), function(el) {return el.value;});
```

But this not works...it works with input

```
var arrUrls = $.map($('input.txt_Url'), function(el) {return el.value;});
```

but not with dropdownlist

Comment: check out the diff http://jsperf.com/map-vs-eac  and i don't know why i'm down voted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost:

```
var arrSelectedAnswers = $('.ddl_NextQuestion').map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6zDw/)

Answer (score 2):

Working Demohttp://jsfiddle.net/zsGWY/2

```
var x ='';
$(".ddl_NextQuestion").each(function(){
   x+=$(this).val()+',';
});
alert(x.slice(0,-1));
```

Comment: Why create a new array if you're going to concatanate strings to it?! There is Array.push you know?

Comment: Probably because of that I don't know. also using arrays is the actual better solution since you don't keep recreating the string each time + no need for the weird substring at the end.

Comment: oh but i gave the correct n better answer still down voted :/

Comment: up voted! yours is far more better! in readability and perfomance